# Upload to playstore without null safety package

Tags: flutter, dart, release, dart-null-safety

I wanna upload some app to playstore my flutter app but I have package without null safety (old package) in my application So, My question can I upload that's to playstore and appstore?
package: ([old package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard))

if you have other idea for like tinder card package please write this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload and it is advised to keep it updated to experience full flow!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can upload just fine ,the thing about null safety is to prevent errors as much as possible all you need to check is that your app sweets the latest play store requerments

Answer (score 0):

You can now, but you should migrate your package before packages that depend on it are migrated. Your null-safe package is usable by packages and apps that don’t use null safety yet, as long as they use Dart 2.12 or later. For example, the Dart and Flutter core libraries are null safe, and they’re still usable by apps that haven’t migrated to null safety.